# $ABCD$ has area $9$. $M$ is in the middle of $AB$ and the edge $BF$ of length $2$ forms an angle of $60º$, Calculate $[CM,CB,BF]$.

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry

> $ABCD$ has area $9$. $M$ is in the middle of $AB$ and the edge $BF$ of length $2$ forms an angle of $60º$. Calculate $[CM,CB,BF]$, knowing that $\mathbb{V}^3$ is oriented by a positive basis.
>
> $\quad\quad$ [image]

As the computation of the determinant ammounts to the volume of the paralelogram, I've obtained the height of $GP$ with the trigonometric identity:

$$\frac{2}{\sin 90}=\frac{a}{\sin 60}=\frac{b}{\sin 30}\\a=\sqrt{3}$$

The volume of the cube is given by $height\times width \times depth$ and hence we have:

$$ height\times width \times depth \\ heigth \times 9 = 9 \sqrt{3}  $$

But in the book, the answer is $3\sqrt{3}$. What is wrong?

Comment: Are we to assume that the figure is a parallelepiped? More seriously, edge $BF$ forms an angle of $60°$ with what: edge $AB$, the plane $ABCD$, or what? Just what is $[CM,CB,BF]$: a volume? And of which figure?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Let's think about $CG$ as $BF$. I assumed that it forms an angle of $60$ on $C$. It's a parallelepiped.

Comment: @Voyska: Please answer the last two questions in the first comment.